# Do narrow utility sinks exist?

Tags: plumbing, garage, sink

I am in need of a really narrow utility sink for my garage. It can not be any wider than twelve inches. Would prefer not to get a wall-mount, but can probably install that, if necessary.

Do they make them this narrow? My Google searches haven't given me any results narrower than 18-22 inches.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might find what you want by looking up bar sinks.  They are made that small.

Comment: Or kitchen prep sinks.

Comment: I accepted answer for bar sinks, because those are cheaper than anything else I'm seeing. Also, the bar sinks tend to have holes for the faucets, which I want.

Answer (score 3):

Make one yourself. Some hard plastic or laminate plus silicone for the seams, and you can make a water-tight box any shape you want. If you're really fancy you could shape or sand the bottom so it slopes toward the drain.

My father used this to make a custom sink for his darkroom, long and shallow, and it's lasted 35 years with no leaks.

Answer (score 2):

You might also find success with a marine sink, for use in the very small boat accommodations. Galley (kitchen) or head (bathroom) sinks would be about this small.

Comment: An example: http://www.ahoycaptain.com/shop/plastimo_sinks_custom.html - As narrow as 6.8" there.